# Singapore during Covid: Do I just need an approval letter?

Tags: visas, covid-19, singapore, canadian-citizens

I need (for family reasons) to go to Singapore. I know I will have to serve a SHN quarantine for 14 days when I arrive. I will serve another when I get home. This trip is important enough to do that. I know I need an [approval letter](https://form.gov.sg/#!/5e3648e9405c180011dc5f9c).

Under normal circumstances, traveling on a Canadian passport, I don't need anything in advance. I buy a plane ticket, I arrive, they let me in. Do I need a [Form 14](https://www.ica.gov.sg/docs/default-source/ica/forms/form14.pdf)? If so, am I applying for a visit pass, an entry visa, or both? If I don't need it, will applying for it actually cause problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you **do** need a Form 14 as part of getting the approval letter. (Not in addition to it.) When you fill out the form for the approval letter, if you choose Short-term visitor, you get new questions that were not there when the form first loads:

[image: filling out approval letter form]

So, Form 14 here I come. I've been told I need to request only a Visit Pass and not a Visa.

Brief update: we got the approval letters.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Things continue to change though, Singapore just today announced they're starting to issue short-term visas again, although approval letters & quarantine for almost all travellers remain required: https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/travellers-from-sabah-required-to-serve-14-day-shn-other-new-measures-for-travellers-also